# Error while compiling with 'g++' using 'NPPExec' plugin with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, c++, nppexec

Everytime I try to run G++ from notepad++ portable I get this error

[image]

I am trying to compile a simple hello world program.
I'm positive that the directories and files exist, but I still get this error.

Although I don't think it concerns this error, I'm using [this tutorial](http://rahul2001.com/weblog/2016/05/my-portable-cc-coding-set-up-with-notepad).

Comment: You might want to avoid using spaces in your file names until you figure it out. Also make sure the amount of backslashes is correct ;)

Comment: Is the error on the compilation or the running of the program (ie is the EXE file created)? In addition to the unquoted spaces pointed out by @OliverSalzburg, I notice there is a double back-slash in the output file name. Some applications don't like this (I don't know if `g++` is one of them), but try running in a subdirectory, which may prevent this. Try cutting and pasting the expanded compilation line into `cmd` and see what happens then you run it from there (in this case you will certainly need to quote the output file name).

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the last part of your statement and change

```
$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe
```

to

```
"$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)$(NAME_PART).exe"
```

by removing `\` character and placing output file name into double quotes